# instanceof Datetime fails when checking a DateTime object

Tags: php, datetime

I tried using a check in PHP 5.5 to see if a variable contains an instanceof DateTime. is_object($value) passes but instanceof DateTime fails

```
if (is_object($value) && $value instanceof DateTime )
{
    $value = $value->format(AppConstant::DATETIME_FORMAT_MYSQL);
}
```

However, this works just fine.

```
if (is_object($value) && is_a($value, "DateTime") )
{
    $value = $value->format(AppConstant::DATETIME_FORMAT_MYSQL);
}
```

From everything I've read, it seems like I should be able to do the former. Why does `instanceof` not work in this case?

Comment: Maybe: `$value instanceof DateTime`

Comment: @Rizier123 sorry that was a typo in the question but not the code

Comment: Then I [can't reproduce your problem](https://3v4l.org/bh6uu)

Comment: Is this code being run inside a namespace? You might need to do `$value instanceof \DateTime`.

Comment: @jszobody it is being run in a namespace, let me test that

Comment: @jszobody that was it, thanks

Comment: @Dallin sure thing. I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is you're inside a namespace, in which case you need to explicitly specify the root namespace for `DateTime`:

```
if (is_object($value) && $value instanceof \DateTime )
```

Or, of course you can specify at the top of your file:

```
use DateTime;

...

if (is_object($value) && $value instanceof DateTime )
```